# UnsafeMutablePointer<Bytef> swift3

Tags: swift3, unsafemutablepointer

The follow line in swift3 make error.

```
out = UnsafeMutablePointer<Bytef>(data.mutableBytes)
```

---

Cannot invoke initializer for type `'UnsafeMutablePointer<Bytef>'` with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'

Comment: I have the same issue... anyone?

Comment: You need converted data.mutableBytes to  UnsafeMutablePointer<T>. I use data.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Bytef.IntegerLiteralType.self).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are asking, however, the way to handle data pointers has changed somewhat in swift3:

### Swift2

When I wanted to access the actual bytes out of a data stream in swift2 you would do some funky pointer stuff casting the data into an unsafe mutable pointer, and then pointing to an array of `[UInt8]` which referenced all the bytes in the data stream directly.

From what you are asking it appears you may have been trying to do something similar in the past.

## Swift3

You now have two commands `withUnsafeBytes` and `withUnsafeMutableBytes`.  In swift2 I used to work with data by taking the bytes and casting it into a pointer array (similar to what it looks like you were doing).

In swift 3 you can now do stuff like this:

```
return data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Bool in
        return 1 ==  Int((bytes[1] & 0x2) >> 1)
}
```

Or this:

```
rawData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
            (bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
            bytes[0] = newValue.rawValue
        }
```

Is this what you are looking for?